# Sorting based on multiple submodel conditions/states

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a Room model that has_many Intervals. Intervals has a start_date and end_date attributes. I want to order the Rooms based on the following conditions

1- Room with no intervals
2- Room with any interval(s) with start_date > Date.today
3- Room without any intervals with start_date > Date.tody

I want to sort the Rooms in such a way that Rooms satisfying 1 come first then Rooms satisfying 2 then 3 using a postgresql query not a method on the model.

While I have no problem finding out which Rooms have no intervals using the query/scope below

```
joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN intervals ON rooms.id = intervals.room_id").where("intervals.id is NULL")
```

I am having issues ordering by the 3 conditions in a single query, I tried the following

```
Room.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN intervals ON rooms.id = intervals.room_id").order("CASE WHEN intervals.id IS NULL THEN 1 END ASC")
```

The issue with this query is that if you call distinct on it you get the error `PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list`, the other issue even when you call distinct here and it works properly you would have sorted by only one condition which is the first 1.

My idea is to generate a function with case conditional to give a value of generated column based on the 3 conditions and give the first the value 1, the second value 2, and the third value 3 and sort by this computed value, whenever I try it though I get hit by the error mentioned above. Any help would be appreciated.

This is my trial to combine all 3 conditions:

```
Room.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN intervals ON rooms.id = intervals.room_id").group("room.id").order("CASE WHEN room.id IS NULL THEN 1 WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN intervals.start_date > '#{Date.today.to_s(:db)}' THEN 1 END) > 0 THEN 2 WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN intervals.start_date > '#{Date.today.to_s(:db)}' THEN 1 END) = 0 THEN 3 END")
```

This however gives the error: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "intervals.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this "specific" case, I would de-normalize the schema for your specific business rules.  Remember, you will probably need pagination at some point and will need to ordering to occur at the db.

To this effect, I would add a column to your model to indicate sort priority:

```
add_column :rooms, :sort_priority, :integer, null: false, default: 0
```

Then in my model for interval, I would include a before_save filter that would set the priority

```
before_save -> {
  if (start_date < blah blah blah)
    self.priority = 1
  elsif (blah blah)
    etc...
  end
}
```

Then I would reflect this in my reference

```
class Room
  has_many :intervals, -> {order :priority, :start_date}
end
```

Comment: The other part here would be adding a cron job at the start of each day to make sure to update the priority of each room at the start of each day because you can't trigger something based on the passage of time. I believe along with the answer this is the complete correct result